# Reading existing field value from SharePoint Custom List fails

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to read the value of a particular field in a SharePoint Custom List.

The Custom List has the following fields: Field1, Field2 and Field3

When I call the code below:

```
public static string GetLastTargetColumnValue(string sharePointSiteUrl, string sharePointListName, string targetColumnName)
        {
            string targetColumnValue = string.Empty;
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sharePointListName);
                var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                var items = list.GetItems(query); 
                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var listItem = items.Last();
                foreach (var fieldValue in listItem.FieldValues)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fieldValue.Key + ":" + fieldValue.Value + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            targetColumnValue = listItem[targetColumnName] as string;
            return targetColumnValue;
        }
```

The error message is:
*Additional information: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.*

The fields which are displayed in the foreach show "Field1" and "Field2". Do I have to explicitly request "Field3". If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

I had to get the internal name before querying the value for some reason. Here is the code that worked:

```
public static string GetLastTargetColumnValue(string sharePointSiteUrl, string sharePointListName, string targetColumnName)
        {
            string targetColumnValue = string.Empty;
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sharePointListName);

                var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(targetColumnName);
                var textField = clientContext.CastTo<FieldText>(field);

                var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                var items = list.GetItems(query);

                clientContext.Load(textField);
                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var listItem = items.Last();
                targetColumnValue = listItem[textField.InternalName] as string;
            }
            return targetColumnValue;
        }
```